# lirc and IR Remote Range

Tags: ubuntu, thinkpad, lirc

So, I finally got around to installing lirc on my Ubuntu machine and it's all going pretty well following the instructions for lirc_sir over at [irDA's ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_use_of_IrDA) page. The main problem I'm running into is poor range, maybe about 4 feet before the remote no longer reaches the IR port on my ThinkPad. I know the remote is well-capable of further, as it works fine on my TV and stereo. I looked through the `lircd.conf` and attempted a good Googling, but I haven't found anything that can point me in the right direction for getting better reception.